# Hit Memory Limit in VBA, will Visual Studio VB be Better?

Tags: vb.net, vba, memory

A userform in Excel VBA started hitting the memory limit of 64 kB today. I expect this interface to grow by 10-15% at least and can easily see it growing larger now. VB6 sounded like it would be better, but I read it also has a 64 kB memory limit of the same kind.

I am stuck using Visual Basic since other workers on this project do not know C++ or any other language. Any quick suggestions besides condensing the form controls?

Comment: What limit are you referring to?

Comment: VB6 and VBA are pretty close to the same thing.

Comment: The issue is too many controls, not gibberish code. The form has multiple multipages, some as many as 10 pages containing multipages of about 4 pages with a number of text boxes, labels, and combo boxes in them.

The userform is just big.

Comment: Why not just split your code out into other modules and/or classes?

Comment: Actually, he is correct, there is a limit on the size of the source code of any single module/class/form in VBA (and still in VB6, IIRC).  The solution is to break those big modules down into smaller ones through subroutine/function/method/property calls.

Comment: It's not the code that I am implementing that is too large. When you add objects like text boxes it adds to the memory of the userform. I also can't put those objects into other modules, they must be part of the actual userform module. There is relatively little other code that I have actually typed into the userform module itself. A sign of proof is the limit occurring and not occurring when I add or remove objects without touching actual code.

Comment: If you add controls using the designer, not through code, it actually edits a source file which you can't normally see - the code to add the controls and position them is just plain VB in that hidden file - so it may well be the file size limit you're reaching. I'm not aware of any per-form memory limit based on the number of controls (although I seem to recall a per-form control count limit of 256 of each control eg textbox)

Comment: Right, I think that is what is happening. I am supposing now vb.net will not change much for me though, I wanted to clarify if it really would have the same kind of limit. Does anyone know why this limit exists for vb.net as well?

Comment: vb.net is a fundamentally different architecture - I don't believe it has any limit other than available resources. Ok, [it seems](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/492143-maximum-number-controls-form) that each control can have a maximum of ~32k child controls - eg each groupbox/tab pane/etc... I suspect you'd run out of memory before you hit that.

Comment: click on "it seems" in my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just written the following simple test...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        While True
            Dim B As New Button
            Me.Controls.Add(B)
            Me.Text = String.Format("Controls: {0}", Me.Controls.Count)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

It started having issues ~4,000 controls. I suspect this is due to the memory limitations on the laptop I'm on.

Comment: Thank you, that's encouraging. I was doing some testing as well and it appears to hit the computer's limits not artificial ones. Thank you for confirming this limit. I did not want to pursue this project without additional reassurance.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. I highly recommend .Net, especially if you're coming from a VB background - you'll find it a refreshing change.

Comment: A couple of things, firstly a typo: It was 4k not 14k. Secondly, I've tracked down the reason for the failure - it seems that windows was unable to allocate additional GDI (Graphical) handles... Outdated article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894500 and more recent and detailed: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/03/31/3322423.aspx - It looks like 10,000 is the default limit for handles per process on the Vista+ OSes

Comment: Finally... It looks like the limit can be bypassed if you _really_ need to (but if you're doing this, you're probably doing something wrong!) http://stackoverflow.com/a/9723784/156755

Comment: That's a nifty trick, but I do hope I will not need to use it. I plan not to.