# SWT uses operating system resources, but what is the limit and how to profile that?

Tags: memory-leaks, java-8, swt, rcp

SWT uses operating system resources so the SWT  memory consumption doesn't depend on the heap (xms xms) and on the non-heap (metaspace). correct me if I'm wrong on that point.

- is there any limit to the resources used by SWT components (colors, fonts, images...)?
- how to know if the limit is reached and how to profile that?
- if this limit is reached, a Java RCP application can crash without a java `OutOfMemoryError` (just a pid file)?

P.S.: I use Sleak to tack the amount of graphic objects currently used by the application

Comment: AFAIK the limit is GDI 65536 handles on Windows per application. The application will crash with an `SWTError: No more handles` if you exceed it.

Comment: [This](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/swt-design-2.html) might be useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Baz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449199/baz) mentioned, the maximum number of GDI handles, which is specific to Windows, influences how many resources a (SWT) process can allocate. See the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723470/whats-the-upper-limit-on-gdi-objects-for-one-process-in-windows-7) for more details. On other platforms, the limit may be different.

As you already found out, [SWT Sleak](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/tools.php) is the right tool to monitor graphics resource usage of SWT applications.

If an application runs out of handles, it does not just 'crash'. An `SWTError` is raised when the limit is reached and an attempt is made to create a new resource.

In general, the exception can be handled like any other exception and after releasing unused resources, new ones can be created.

IIRC, the default exception handler of RCP applications will open a dialog that asks the user to exit the application gracefully in this case.

However, running out of handles in an SWT application is usually a sign that your strategy of how widgets are created/used is wrong.

A common strategy to reduce the number of resources is to use lazy/virtual `Tree`s and `Table`s and to create widgets only when they become visible and dispose of them when no longer needed. In a `TabFolder`, for example, you would defer populating the `TabItem` unless it gets selected.